# Binding Property to Behavior Error

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, attachedbehaviors

What I want to do is to bind a Property of my `ViewModel` to a `Behavior` in XAML.

So first of all here is my Code for the Behavior in Xaml.

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <common:FrameworkElementRenderTransformBehavior
                                   WidthPercentage="1"
                                   WidthMultiple="1"
                                   HeightPercentage="1"
                                   HeightMultiple="1"
                                   RelativeHeight="{Binding RelativeHeight}"
                                   RelativeWidth="{Binding RelativeWidth}"/>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

But all I get is an `Error`. I think it is a general problem to bind a a property to a behavior, but there have to be a simple way to do this.

I took this [Example](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/07/22/tips-and-tricks-for-using-xaml-controls-in-your-universal-windows-apps/) and it is working well, but as I said not with Bindings. I just added `RelativeWidth` and `RelativeHeight`.

Comment: Have you set the `DataContext`?

Comment: Can I set the DataContext of a Behavior ? The general `DataContext` on the `UserControl` works well.

Comment: Can you provide the full information about error you have got?

Comment: Maybe it helps that I just got 1 RelativeSize each Page. But I have to bind it at least `OneTime`.

Comment: Ok I end in the global debugger bevor my app can starts. The Inner Exception is `+  [Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException] {Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Failed to assign to property '%0'. [Line: 48 Position: 37]} Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException
`

Comment: If I just did something wrong that would be great! But  I think there are problems with binding in Behaviors in the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

All right I solved it. I took normal Propertys and not DependencyPropertys.